# Understanding MERGE in context of force graph

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to learn d3. I am looking at a force directed graph [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/c48022f55ebc76e6adafa77cf466da35)

I am trying to understand what MERGE is doing in the context of this function

```
function updateLinks() {
 // we select the links class which is a group under the svg.
  var u = d3.select('.links')
// then we selectAll line... now line doesn't exist, so we are creating it
    .selectAll('line')
// then we are attaching the data of links to this structure that we created.
    .data(links)

// this initiates a for loop
  u.enter()
// in that loop...
    .append('line')
    .merge(u)
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.source.x
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.target.y
    })

  u.exit().remove()
}
```

In searching try to understand merge, I've come across two basic kinds of responses: 1) Explanations of merge joining two arrays, like concat or flat and 2) code examples with little explanation.

While I understand the concept of joining two arrays, I don't see how u.enter().merge(u) works. It looks like this function is joining u with itself. Can someone explain this in simple terms?

I have included comments indicating the extend of my understanding.

Thank you

Comment: Since you're learning D3: that's a really bad example. The author of that code is merging the selections inside the tick function, 50 or more times per second. That's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three types of D3 selections:

- Update: this represents all of the nodes that already exist for all of the data that already exists. The first time you run `updateLinks()`, it will be empty because none of the data have nodes yet.
- Enter: this contains “ghost” nodes for data points that don’t yet have nodes in the DOM. The first time you run `updateLinks()`, everything thing will be in here because you haven’t yet created nodes for any of your data points.
- Exit: this contains the nodes for which there is no longer data.

At the top of your function, when you first create `u` and bind the data, `u` represents your update selection. It contains no actual nodes the first time you run your function, because they have to be appended in the enter selection later.

Typically, you want all of your nodes to look the same (relatively, based on each one’s datum). So, a common pattern is to

1. Create the update selection, as you have.
2. Create an enter selection and append new nodes.
3. **Merge** the update and enter selections back together.
4. Apply attribute values based on data.

If you didn’t merge, you’d have to duplicate all of your code setting the `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` attributes. But since you can append new nodes using the enter selection and merge those back into the existing update selection, you only have to set all of those attributes once, to the newly enlarged update selection.

For more, see Mike Bostock’s [Thinking with Joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), a most-read for all new D3 users, along with the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/3808218).